# Why is HashSet<T>.IsReadOnly explicit?

Tags: c#, interface, hashset, icollection, explicit-interface

This

```
var h = new HashSet<int>();
var r = h.IsReadOnly;
```

does not compile. I have to do

```
var r = ((ICollection<int>)h).IsReadOnly;
```

why wasn't IsReadOnly implemented normally?

(I'm not asking **how**, but **why**)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm guessing its because, while HashSet implements ICollection, IsReadOnly has no meaning for HashSet.  In fact, if you reflect it, the property always returns false.  Implementing it explicitly hides this method from the public interface.

Another reason is because the ICollection interface may be implemented because of incidental reasons (e.g., to support xaml serialization) rather than because its necessary to the primary use of the class.  So implementing it explicitly can keep the clutter out of the class' interface.

Comment: Ah, yes, that does make sense. HashSet also hides IsReadOnly for the same reason I guess, hence the compile error if you try to use it.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to implement ICollection for xaml serialization; collections must implement IDictionary or IList.  It was just an example of occasions when you might need to implment an interface for incidental reasons.

Answer (score 5):

There are basically two reasons why you would resort to an explicit interface implementation (source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664591(loband).aspx)):

1. You implement multiple interfaces with members containing the same signatures, and you want these members to behave differently.
2. An interface member is not of particular interest to the class, but is required in order to reference objects by the interface.

For `HashSet<T>`, the latter case applies, as a hash set is never read only and `IsReadOnly` will thus always return `false`.